# Getting selected font

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jcombobox, jtextarea

hi how do i add the selected font using jcombobox and put it into my label? for example when someone select the font it will get the selected font and the label will get it so and area.gettext will show the selected font

```
  b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
GraphicsEnvironment graphEnviron = 
                       GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                Font[] allFonts = graphEnviron.getAllFonts();

                JComboBox<Font> fontBox = new JComboBox<Font>(allFonts);
                fontBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
                   @Override
                   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
                         Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                      if (value != null) {
                         Font font = (Font) value;
                         value = font.getName();
                      }
                      return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
                            isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                   }
                });

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(fontBox));
        String myString=area.getText();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(myString);
        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
        label.setFont(font);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f.getComponent(0),label);
    }
});
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: `Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);` should be something like.. `Font font = allFonts.getSelectedItem().deriveFont(12f));`. For anything beyond 'something like' post that MCVE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it says cannot invoke getSelectedItem() on array Font[]

Comment: Where is that **M-C-V-E**? I'll mot waste further time in this until you put the effort in..

Comment: @AndrewThompson solved my problem its      label.setFont(new Font((String) fontComboBox.getSelectedItem(), Font.ITALIC, 16));.. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :) Now you might delete the question or ***better*** answer your own question below.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i don't think you can delete the question you posted?

Comment: Of course you can! Look at the links below the question tags. N.B. but you're blocked from deleting questions for which there is an *accepted answer*..